# Loading multiple views using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 4 pages in view such as

```
layout/header.php,
layout/header_assets.php,
user/main.php,
layout/footer.php
```

i want to load these multiple view so i have used this code in controller

```
$this->load->view('layout/header_assets');
    $this->load->view('user/main',$data);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');
```

but i have got an issue :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost/game/assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
test
</body>
</html>
<footer>

</footer>
```

I want html code in proper way, header_assets load in head tag, footer load in body tag.

but right now if i load first header_assets and than load main.php.
so header_assets load first after that main.php

I want it in this way

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost/game/assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
</head>

<body>
test

<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$this->load->vars($data);` before loading views. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a folder `includes` under `view` and create a page `template` and add the below code in page `template`-

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view($middle);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');   
?>
```

And in your controller you can just call the template and pass your data like below-

```
$this->data['middle'] = 'public/existing_mem'; // view page to be included
 $this->load->view('includes/template',$this->data);
```

Answer (score 2):

For your Question

**In Controller**

```
$this->load->view('layout/header_assets',$data); # Change
$this->load->view('user/main',$data);
$this->load->view('layout/footer');
```

---

**Best option is**

> A file should contain  3 part.

1. Header
2. Body
3. Footer.

**In Header**

> There is only contain

1. Meta Tags
2. All CSS and JS

   ```
   <html lang="en">    
   <head>
       <meta>....
       <link href="">....
       <script>....
   </head>
   ```

**In Body**

> This should contain page displaying part and all codes. This contain

1. `<body>` tag start ....
2. All rest of your code

**In Footer**

> This should contain

1. Copyright
2. Move top(id required)
3. `</body>` tag close with `</html>`

> So you can load this three View in codeigniter by

```
$this->load->view('layout/header');
$this->load->view('user/main',$data);
$this->load->view('layout/footer')
```